# Finding the general term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

I would like to find an expression for the sequence $\;\{a_n\},\;n=0,\,1,\,2,\,3,\,\dots,\;$ $$-\frac{1}{6},\,\frac{2}{7},\,\frac{5}{8},\,\frac{8}{9},\,\frac{11}{10},\,\ldots$$

So by trial and error I got $$a_n\,=\,\frac{3n-1}{n+6},\; n=0,\,1,\,2,\,\ldots$$

How does one approach these types of problems in general and in particular, the present problem, other than by trial and error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> $$-\frac{1}{6},\,\frac{2}{7},\,\frac{5}{8},\,\frac{8}{9},\,\frac{11}{10},\,\ldots
> \quad a_n = \;\;?$$

***Look for patterns:***

- *Numerator*: each term *increases* by $3$, starting at $-1$ when $n = 0\;\; \rightarrow \;\;3\cdot n - 1\;$?
- *Denominator*: each term *increases* by $1$, starting at $6$ when $n = 0 \;\; \rightarrow \;\;1\cdot n+6\;$?

*Note that both the numerators and the denominators form [**arithmetic progressions**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)*

***Test it***:

$$\{a_n\},\; n\in \{0, 1, 2, 3, ...\};\;\;a_n\;=\; \dfrac{3n - 1}{n+6} \quad = \quad -\frac{1}{6},\,\frac{2}{7},\,\frac{5}{8},\,\frac{8}{9},\,\frac{11}{10},\,\frac{14}{11},\, \frac{17}{12},\,\ldots$$

If testing it fails, try to "tweak it" the expression of the general term (reevaluate to ensure correct term for $a_0$, ensure that the numerator and denominators do, in fact, represent arithmetic progressions...etc.)

---

Not applicable to your particular sequence, but a useful tool to have in your toolbox of strategies: Another progression you'll see arise frequently in sequences is the ***[geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)***, another "good to know" progression to learn so you can spot it when it occurs, and make use of how to form the general expression for a term in such a sequence.

Comment: So if the sequence starts from zero and it is an AP, would the general term be $a_n=a_0 +nd$?

Comment: Yes! I think you've got it: $a_0$ being the term at n = 0.

Comment: Glad to help, Gorg!